# Two questions about the launch mode in Android

Tags: android, launchmode

when I use `startActivityForResult()` to start `Activity2` in `Activity1`, if `Activity1` and `Activity2` are not in the same task stack, the `resultCode` is 0(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED).

IF `Activity1`'s launchMode is standard and `Activity2`'s launchMode is singleTask, the `resultCode` I got is 0.

What happened in stack?

If Activity1's launchMode is singleTop and Activity1 use the startActivityForResult() method to start itself, the stack has two instances of  Activity1.

What happened in stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answers myself.

For the first question,I found the answer in the note of method startActivityForResult(Intent,int,Bundle).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhqub.png)

As shown in the following figure,the shown Activity may be ActivityX if ActivityY finishes ,so it immediately receive a cancel result for the uncertain result.It just happens when api is below 20.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0HMF.png)

For the next question,I found the answer in source code.

`ActivityStack topStack = getFocusedStack();
            ActivityRecord top = topStack.topRunningNonDelayedActivityLocked(notTop);
            if (top != null && r.resultTo == null) {
                Slog.d("DDY", "========------ " );
                if (top.realActivity.equals(r.realActivity) && top.userId == r.userId) {
                    if (top.app != null && top.app.thread != null) {
                        if ((launchFlags&Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP) != 0
                            || r.launchMode == ActivityInfo.LAUNCH_SINGLE_TOP
                            || r.launchMode == ActivityInfo.LAUNCH_SINGLE_TASK) {
                            ......
                             top.deliverNewIntentLocked(callingUid, r.intent);`

When a Activity try to start itself,r.resultTo is not null,so it start with standard mode.